# Bought a Genesis bicycle for £100 and wanted to know if it was worth it since I can't quite identify the exact model

Tags: road-bike, identify-this-bike

[image]

I'm not seeing any cue in regards to the model, thought that maybe there's someone here who could help me identify it.
Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Questions seeking product/service/learning material recommendations or item valuations are off-topic because they tend to become obsolete quickly. Instead describe the situation or specific problem you are trying to solve, or try chatting about it in The Velodrome

Comment: You probably were not badly ripped off, if the bike is in good condition.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like a moderately modern road bike that has been refitted with MTB flat bars to make it a rigid hybrid commuter.

Modern threadless steerer and a cartridge BB suggests its within the last decade or so.

As for value - if you needed a bike and could afford it out of pocket, then you're doing fine financially.  Now just ride it and enjoy not paying for operating costs of a motor vehicle, or per-ride costs of public transport.

Comment: If you know a question is going to be closed, you shouldn’t answer it. It only confuses the newbs. Instead, write your answer in a comment.

Comment: @RoboKaren you're right, the cost/value component makes it closeworthy.  But the "identify this model" part  is what I answered, and my line on value deliberately avoided answering as expected.